# Apply inner expression filter on IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression, iqueryable

Suppose I have the following objects:

```
public class Source { public string Name; }
public class Target { public string Name; }
public class Result 
{ 
   public Source SourceObj; 
   public Target TargetObj; 
}
```

Now, obtaining `IQueryable<Result>` from somewhere I would like to prepare expression filter for it just having Target filter as expression: `Expression<Func<Target, bool>> filter`. The filter method signature looks like this:

```
public Expression<Func<Result, bool>> Filter(IQueryable<Result> collection, Expression<Func<Target, bool>> targetFilter)
{ 
   in result expression: "in given collection select items where their property TargetObj satisfies targetFilter"
}
```

Any suggestions will be very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What's the question here?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want an expression as a return for your `Filter` method, you don't need `IQueryable<Result> collection`.

```
public Expression<Func<Result, bool>> Filter(Expression<Func<Target, bool>> targetFilter)
{
    Func<Target, bool> func = targetFilter.Compile();
    Expression<Func<Result, bool>> resultExpression = r => func(r.TargetObj);

    return resultExpression;
}
```

usage:

```
var results = new List<Result>()
{
   new Result() { TargetObj = new Target() { Name = "A" }},
   new Result() { TargetObj = new Target() { Name = "B" }},
   new Result() { TargetObj = new Target() { Name = "C" }},
};

var expression = Filter(r => r.Name == "B");
var func = expression.Compile();

var filteredResults = results.Where(r => func(r));
```

The sample filtered result here would return the target with B. It would make more sense for me to use Linq Where directly based on my understanding of your goal.

EDIT: Since you've added a new factor into your question here is how you can add the target filter to the base filter.

```
public Expression<Func<Result, bool>> Filter(Expression<Func<Result, bool>> baseFilter, Expression<Func<Target, bool>> targetFilter)
{
    Func<Result, bool> baseFunc = baseFilter.Compile();
    Func<Target, bool> targetFunc = targetFilter.Compile();
    Expression<Func<Result, bool>> resultExpression = r => baseFunc(r) && targetFunc(r.TargetObj);

    return resultExpression;
}
```

Comment: To be more clear I just want to correct my question a bit. Suppose, I'm building a complex filter expression to query Results. Instead of  `IQueryable<Result> collection` my Filter method should have baseFilter parameter and look like `public Expression<Func<Result, bool>> Filter(Expression<Func<Result, bool>> baseFilter, Expression<Func<Target, bool>> targetFilter)`. The purpose of this method is somehow "combine" these two filters making the targetFilter as an "inner" filter of baseFilter one.  Thanks

Comment: @TimurGinesin I updated my answer to show how you can combine your base and target filter expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entierly sure I understood your goal correctly, but here's what I think is probably the thing you want.

With the linq `Select`, you can map an element from your source collection. So here we are mapping the result to the target and then apply your target filter.

```cs
public IQueryable<Target> GetFilteredTargets(IQueryable<Result> collection, Expression<Func<Target, bool>> targetFilter)
{
    return collection.Select(result => result.Target).Where(targetFilter);
}
```